# Unity Tweak Tool changed fonts and can't get Ubuntu back to normal

Tags: unity, android, fonts, sublime-text

Good day all.

I installed Unity Tweak tools some time ago. Recently I was playing around with it and changed a lot of things.

Since then my applications behave a little different especially fonts and sizes.

I did restore but it has been stuck that way.[image: Android studio]

This is how my Android Studio looks like now. I can't do anything. Tried changing the font size in it but even my Sublime Text is affected.

[image: Sublime Text sidebar.]

Please how do i get back to normal?
Was thinking of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

After so much frustration and digging around.

I finally solved it!

First i tried resetting Ubuntu:
Log in as root

```
exec sudo -i
```

Try configuring unconfigured packages:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Update the contents of the repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Try to fix missing dependencies:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Update your system:

```
 apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reinstall Ubuntu desktop:

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Remove unnecessary packages:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Delete downloaded packages already installed:

```
apt-get clean
```

Reboot the system:

```
reboot
```

All these helped in reducing the weight on the system but nothing else.

Then i decided to do this:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

it reset GNOME 3 settings.
My Computer now looks like i just installed Ubuntu but with my files still in it.

So happy.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands to reset those settings to default:

```
cd ~/.config/dconf
mv user user.bak
```

And then relogin.